# Android API < 8 where did they go?

Tags: android, sdk, android-api-levels

In the sdk manager I can only see API levels 8+, how can I download api lower than that. I want to make my app compatible with 2.1.X, 2.1, and 2.0 at least

Comment: Post a screenshot of your SDK Manager please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SDK Manager should be showing you API Level 3, 4, and 7 for download, with the others showing up if you check the "Obsolete" checkbox. You might need to clear your cache (Tools > Options, then click "Clear Cache" button) and reload (Packages > Reload).

Bear in mind that the ones that show up when you check Obsolete are Obsolete for a reason: there are no devices that run those versions. Please do not waste your time to "make [your] app compatible with... 2.0", as there are no devices that run Android 2.0. All devices that once had Android 2.0 (specifically the initial production run of the Motorola DROID) have since been upgraded to at least Android 2.1.