# Using methods from android API level 4

Tags: android, api

I try to use a specific method which is as far as i know only available in API level 4.
Accordingly to this post: [Android API < 8 where did they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018073/android-api-8-where-did-they-go), all devices run at least Android 2.1 which matches my observations, I have set the min/max/target api level in my app to 4 and used api level 4 to compile my app, but the device runs it with level 8. 
Is there any way i could get access to the methods only available on the old api?

Thank you very much for your help.
Tom

Comment: every deprecated method has a replacement.. find out and use newer version..

Comment: The method i am talking about is sendRawPDU and is a private function in SmsManager. I did not found much information about its replacment, if there is any. I used this tutorial with the same device described there: <http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/11/calling-private-methods-in-android.html>

Answer (score 1):

Using a `private` method is always risky...
As for your question, I had a look at the source code and it seems that the method is quite simple and you can just add it directly to your code:

```
private void sendRawPdu(byte[] smsc, byte[] pdu, PendingIntent sentIntent,
        PendingIntent deliveryIntent) {
    try {
        ISms iccISms = ISms.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("isms"));
        if (iccISms != null) {
            iccISms.sendRawPdu(smsc, pdu, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        // ignore it
    }
}
```

The `ISms.sendRawPdu()` is declared `public`, so I hope that implementation is still there.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/telephony/SmsManager.java#SmsManager.sendRawPdu%28byte%5B%5D%2Cbyte%5B%5D%2Candroid.app.PendingIntent%2Candroid.app.PendingIntent%29

Comment: The `ServiceManager` class is marked with `@Hide` annotation, which means it's not available to normal Android app. A simple copy and paste is not sufficient here.

Comment: I would use reflections as described in the tutorial from my post above. It worked with other methods  - sendRawPdu was missing in the reflection...

Comment: @TactMayers I see. I didn't look that far. If all this stuff is hidden/private I figure it's not a good idea to use it anyway. Guybrush, as this stuff has changed already a long time ago, I suggest you look for another, more system conform way to solve what you want to do.